# Android - Adding several MapFragments dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, mapfragment

For my application I have to achieve something near from a launcher : I have to provide the ability to add, remove, resize and drag n drop dynamically some UI elements (let's call them "widgets", but they are not Android AppWidgets) . It works pretty fine, but one of these "widgets" contains a MapFragment, and I am not able to add it twice, neither to remove it and add it again.

For the moment, each "widget" is inherited from FrameLayout. The MapFragment is loaded from a xml. The problem is that we can't set a Fragment id by code, and if I do it in the xml, I have obviously the same id for all of my maps. So I get this exception :

```
03-20 09:55:35.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Binary XML file line #24: Duplicate id 0xffffffff, tag map,
or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

Here is the code for the fragment :

```
...
<fragment
    android:tag="map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
...

View.inflate(getContext(), layout, R.layout.widget_map);
```

So here I am, completely stuck ^^. I already search through stackoverflow and the internet without founding a solution.

Moreover, I'm using the Android Maps API V2, and I get some GC printing in the console each time I change the orientation of the screen (so when the map is redrawn), must I worry about them ?

```
03-20 10:02:41.820: D/dalvikvm(19650): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1929K, 17% free 11579K/13940K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 44ms
03-20 10:02:42.250: D/dalvikvm(19650): GC_CONCURRENT freed 382K, 14% free 12123K/13940K, paused 3ms+13ms, total 67ms
03-20 10:02:42.250: D/dalvikvm(19650): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 51ms
03-20 10:02:42.328: D/dalvikvm(19650): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2114K, 21% free 11099K/13940K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 45ms
03-20 10:02:42.328: D/dalvikvm(19650): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
```

Any advice would be welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried giving different `id`s to your different maps?

```
    android:id="@+id/map1"

    android:id="@+id/map2" // etc...
```

Otherwise, you can use  [`setId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29) on your views.

If working with `Fragment`s doesn't work, you can add

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

in your XML, and set it up in your code. See [Google's Maps V2 Demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code) `RawMapViewDemoActivity`'s code.

For the GC calls, I wouldn't worry, `MapView`s need a lot of memory, and a screen rotation destroys and recreate all your views, so that's a normal thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I juste tried with MapViews, and it works, but using MapViews I have to forward all the activity lifecycle functions to my "widget", which is quite annoying :/ .

For the fragments, I can't give differents ids : I'm using the same XML file, to load several fragments. So in the XML I can't set the id, because if I do it it will be the same for all of my fragments, and I can't do it by code, because… We can't set fragment's id's by code >< !!

…

Comment: ...

Ok for the GC calls… I red some articles about the API V2 and memory leaks, seems like Google has released it to soon (and moreover, there is IMHO a HUGE lack of functionalities / flexibility :/ ).

If if choose to continue with MapViews, I will accept your answer, thank you !